Azure Function App Multiple Connection Strings Via Terraform
I am trying to add multiple connection string in an azure function app settings via the terraform but getting error
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "ali_test_fa" {
name                       = local.function_app_function_app_name
resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.sandbox_resource_group.name
location                   = 
data.azurerm_resource_group.sandbox_resource_group.location
service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.ali_test_asp.id
storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.ali_test_fa_st.name
storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.ali_test_fa_st.primary_access_key
tags                       = local.tags
dynamic "connection_string" {
for_each = toset(local.connection_strings)
content {
  name  = each.value.name
  type  = each.value.type
  value = each.value.value
}

}
Error: each.value cannot be used in this context
│
│   on resource_linux_function-app.tf line 26, in resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "ali_test_fa":
│   26:       name  = each.value.name
│
│ A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it is unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in its    
│ "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your configuration to work around this error.
╵
╷
│ Error: each.value cannot be used in this context
│
│   on resource_linux_function-app.tf line 27, in resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "ali_test_fa":
│   27:       type  = each.value.type
│
│ A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it is unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in its    
│ "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your configuration to work around this error.
╵
╷
│ Error: each.value cannot be used in this context
│
│   on resource_linux_function-app.tf line 28, in resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "ali_test_fa":
│   28:       value = each.value.value
│
│ A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it is unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in its    
│ "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your configuration to work around this error.

I have specified connection strings like following:
local = {
connection_strings = [
    {
      value = "I am a sensitive sql database connection string"
      type  = "SQLServer"
      name  = "connection_string_sql_database"
    }
  ]
}

I have tried following but no success:
for_each = local.connection_strings
or
for_each = { for inst in local.connection_strings : inst.name => inst }

Update1 : Looks like following worked
dynamic "connection_string" {
for_each = local.connection_strings
content {
  name  = connection_string.value.name
  type  = connection_string.value.type
  value = connection_string.value.value
}

}

What is the terraform version you are using! @Ali

required_version = ">= 0.15"


A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it│ unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in│ its "for_each" expression.

The error each.value cannot be used in this context means that there is no each.value to refer here with the dynamic "connection_string" block as you are defining input as a list of maps.
Modify the dynamic block as shown below if you are passing values by defining in the locals block.
dynamic "connection_string" {
for_each = local.connection_strings
content {
  name  = connection_string.value.name
  type  = connection_string.value.type
  value = connection_string.value.value
}

main.tf:
locals {
  connection_strings = [
    {
      value = "I am a sensitive sql database connection string"
      type  = "SQLServer"
      name  = "connection_string_sql_database"
    }
  ]
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "xxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "funcresg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "jafunctionappsa"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "jahnewplan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "example" {
  name                = "jahexamplesampp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

dynamic "connection_string" {
for_each = local.connection_strings
content {
  name  = connection_string.value.name
  type  = connection_string.value.type
  value = connection_string.value.value
}
}
site_config{}
}

Output:


Alternatively, you can use variable block rather than locals by taking the input as list(object) as shown below.
variable "connection_strings" {
  type = list(object({
    value  = string
    type  = string
    name = string
  }))
  default = [{
      value = "I am a sensitive sql database connection string"
      type  = "SQLServer"
      name  = "connection_string_sql_database"
    }] 
}

dynamic block in main.tf:
dynamic "connection_string" {
    for_each = var.connection_strings
    content {
      name = each.value.name
      type = each.value.type
      value = each.value.value
    }
  }

Reference: Template registry - azurerm_linux_function_app
Github for relevant issue.
